# {{ form.non_field_errors }} with django-crispy-forms

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I have the following django form using crispy-forms:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h2 class="panel-title">TEAM SELECTION</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">{{ form.team1|as_crispy_field }}</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">{{ form.team2|as_crispy_field }}</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"; margin-bottom: 2cm;>Submit</button></div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Everything looks amazing except the `{{ form.non_field_errors }}` part. It just looks like a bullet list as follows:

- You picked the same team!

Does anyone know how I can have make the `{{ form.non_field_errors }}` look as exciting as the rest of the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [`as_crispy_errors`](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_templatetags.html#templatetags.crispy_forms_filters.as_crispy_errors) filter:

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{{ form|as_crispy_errors }}
```

Comment: I thought that because I was using individual fields I could not use this.  Thanks for the information. Now, to try and make it more user friendly :)